# Generic worker for BackgroundService in .net core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, background-service, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

i want to build the generic worker for BackgroundService in .net core 3.0.

Where we might have a 50 worker with same kind of work except the two parameter 
 different need to be pass.

Is there a way to add the hostedservice to ConfigureServices with object
 and get that object in the generic worker class and work with it?.
 Like ,

```
    var workers = new List<WorkerModel>(); 

    foreach(var worker in workers){  
          services.AddHostedService<GenericWroker<WorkerModel>(item)>();
    }
```

guidance to get the work done would be appreciate.

Comment: What do you want to pass?

Comment: For my scenario, i do have a 50 database, and 1 master database. 
i want to sync in background a specific table of each database to the master database.
For, this it's not a good idea to build the each worker for each database. 
So, i wonder if it is possible to build the generic background worker for this.
I understood if not wrong,registering a hostedservice to configureservice would be a one background worker.
So i need to pass the connectionstring of each database to the generic worker and register them in a service to work it in individual worker.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you need is that your GenericWorker to implement the abstract class `BackgroundService` and register this in the Startup as transient. Then you will need a pool of GenericWorkers, basically a manager, after that whenever you need a GenericWorker you should instantiate one by doing the `Serviceprovider.GetRequiredService<GenericWorker<WorkerModel>>()`, with this solution every time you request the ServiceProvider for a GenericWorker you will get a new instance.